# Using Spring Cloud Vault to secure passwords, etc. in Spring Boot apps?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, hashicorp-vault

I have made several searches to secure all the sensitive data in the `application.properties` and finally concluded to use Spring Cloud Vault by HashiCorp.

As far as I see, I can keep all the secrets, etc., as key-value pairs in this mechanism. However, I could not be sure and understand the following points. Could you help me pls?

1. While keeping all the sensitive data in Vault, I think we need to provide a token in the Spring Boot app to access this data. So, for a production environment, suppose that I send the app to the customer, then should they provide this token via environment variables? Or are there any other alternatives that are secure also?
2. How the app uses the secrets kept in Vault? Does it retrieves them whenever it needs or retrieve at the startup and then keep them in memory, etc., in the server or Docker container (based on the config)?

Comment: @seenukarthi  do you have an idea about the question besides formatting bullets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vault tokens should to be injected as environment variables. If you have a platform like k8 or OpenShift the Vault token itself can be stored as a secret.

Springboot loads the secrets from [Vault at startup](https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/24/managing-secrets-with-vault).

Here is a snippet of our DeploymentConfig template file:

```
kind: DeploymentConfig
spec:
  strategy:
    spec:
      containers:   
        - name: {{ .Release.Name }}
          env:
            - name: VAULT_API
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: global-secrets
                  key: vaultapi
            - name: VAULT_TOKEN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: global-secrets
                  key: vaulttoken
```

Comment: Many thanks for help. Then, if we don't use k8 or OpenShift, then we should pass the tokens for Vault via environment variables **for both, dev and prod**, right?

Comment: On the other hand, the link seems to be useful, but its date is old (June 24, 2016) and I am wondering if there is an updated version of this original article. Any idea?

Comment: by the way, cannot vote up. any vote up please for the question?

Comment: Yes, different vault tokens (and probably) for each environment. Article may be old but it still works like this today in my vault, spring, k8 environments.

Comment: *and probably URLs for each environment

Comment: Wonderful... Voted up and marked as answer.

Comment: Actually I am looking for a proper example that is using Docker with proper config, but unfortunately could not find. Do you have any idea fr a proper example besides the one you shared above?

Comment: I have added a snippet of dc template that we use to pick up the vault token etc from secrets

Comment: Thanks  a lot. I am wondering how should I secure the token that is used for accessing vault. Normally I use it in an `.env` file, but when sending the app in production mode to the customer, should I make them to update the token and proceed (the token in the .env file will be used bot in Docker compose and in the app). Normally I ignore .env file, for this reason I am confused about how should I proceed?

Comment: Put the vault token in the cluster management (k8 or OpenShift) secrets store, never in .env. Hence valueFrom.secretKeyRef.name=global-secrets and valueFrom.secretKeyRef.key=vaulttoken

Comment: Ok, finally you have changed my mind to a proper way. But IU am not sure which one could be integrated more easily. So, for just a simple app to learn Spring Cloud Vault, which one should I prefer to keep vault token? k8 or OpenShift?

Comment: I have a plan to learn k8, then is it better to use k8 for this purpose instead of OpenShift?

Comment: k8 is more widely used. OpenShift is a thin layer on top of k8.

Comment: Then I should definitely learn k8 and keep my token in it when using vault. Thanks.